# how to use environment variables in vim-dap

Tags: debugging, neovim

I'm using [nvim-dap](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap) to setup debug my node app. It is not reading any of the env variables from my `.env` file. When I run nvim-dap the following log:

```
console.log("db name: "+   process.env.MYSQL_DB_NAME);
```

it returns undefined.

When I run `:h dap-adapter` I get the following

```
For executable the following options are supported:


    command: string         -- command to invoke
    options?: {
      env?: {}              -- Set the environment variables for the command
```

but it seems this is only made for the env variable name:

```
- Some variables are supported:
  ..
  - `${env:Name}`: Environment variable named `Name`, for example: `${env:HOME}`.
```

How can I actually give it key/value pairs of environment variables?

Comment: https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/issues